# When is this statement true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Under what conditions is the following equation true

$$x_1=x_2+x_2x_1^2-x_1x_2^2
$$

I thought it was true only when $x_1=x_2$, but apparently there are more possibilities than this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: factor the right most two terms. Then solve for zero and continue factoring.

Comment: So, factoring the terms gives me $x_1x_2(x_1-x_2) = 0$ which would mean that $x_1x_2 = 0$ is a possibility. Would that mean this is also true when either $x_1,x_2 = 0$?

Comment: You did factor it correctly, but just because that entire term is zero, that doesn't mean that the equation is true. Now that you've factored it, solve the original equation for zero, say by moving everything over to the left side. (The other answer suggests you subtract $x_2$ from both sides; that will move that term to the left.)

Comment: Ok, I ended up getting $x_1x_2 = 1$ after moving the terms around. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, excellent! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract $x_2$ from both sides, you can factor out $x_1-x_2$.  There is another factor.  If that one is zero....

Answer (score 2):

$$
x_1=x_2+x_2x_1^2-x_1x_2^2\iff (x_2-x_1)-x_2x_1(x_2-x_1)=0\iff (x_2-x_1)(1-x_2x_1)=0\\
\iff(x_2=x_1)\lor\left(x_2=\frac1{x_1}\right)
$$